# Phrase for having nearly completed something

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Is there is a phrase for when you're very close to achieving something you've been working on?

When the detective gets that final clue, but hasn't quite solved the mystery yet. When you've done 90% of the work and rest is easily achievable.

I keep thinking it's something like "you can taste it", or "the home straight" but that doesn't quite sound right

Comment: Using an American football analogy, you could say you're _at the one-yard line_. But as I think about it, I'm not at all sure that's common even in America.

Comment: There's also the [90/90 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninety-ninety_rule), though I have a feeling that's not what you meant...

Comment: "All we lack is finishing up". :-)

Comment: The 90/90 rule was what first came to mind, but "we're in the home stretch" is the phrase I'd likely choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could say *on the [verge](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verge)*

> a limit beyond which something occurs; brink   ⇒ on the verge of ecstasy [*Collins*]

Alternatives are

> *[threshold](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/threshold)*: the starting point of an experience, event, or venture [*Collins*]
>
> and
>   *[brink](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brink)*: the verge of an event or state [*Collins*]

A phrase along the lines you mentioned is *[home stretch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/homestretch)*

> The last part of an activity or campaign [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

Comment: Synonymously, *on the cusp*.

Comment: @talrnu That sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could say the job is "all but finished". It literally means everything has been done except for declaring the job finished, or perhaps performing some finishing touches. Not to be confused with "anything but finished" which has the exact opposite meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're thinking of *[the home stretch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/home+stretch)*:

> that part of a race course between the last curve and the winning
>   post.
>
> *Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

> Wait for it...

(like when a little kid wants to grab the dish of ice cream before his mother is done filling it)

> You are burning up!

(from the little kids' game Hide-the-thimble.  The closer you get to finding it, the warmer you are.  When you've just about discovered it, the others shout this phrase.)